# Calling multiple scans in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Say I have the following url:

```
url = "https://instagram.com/username/"
```

And I want to extract "username". Is it okay to scan 3 times? Or is this going to be much slower?

```
url.scan(/instagram.com\/.+\//).first.scan(/\/.+\//).first.scan(/[^\/]/).first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
url = "https://instagram.com/username/somewhat/something/"

url.scan(/https:\/\/instagram.com\/(\w+)\//).first 
# => ["username"]
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/BUQa/3)